# jQuery data attribute is being returned differently for multiple requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, closures

I have an element:

```
  <a id="contactUsLink" class="modalButton homepageButton modalOpenButton" href="#" data-modal='{ldelim} "target" : "#contactDialogue", "action" : "open" {rdelim}'>Contact Us</a>
```

I assign a closure to the jQuery click event

```
$('#contactUsLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).data('modal');
    modeless.modal(this);
});
```

I process the data attribute in my namespaced javascript function `nameless.modal()`, I do various things with the `DOM` including animating various divs etc.

When I click the link again the varaiable data is returning the data attribute for another element.

I'm very confused. Obviously my other code is interfering with jQuery somehow, but as all my variables and function names are in my own namespace....how?

Have a missed something else?

Comment: I added the var data to establish that data was incorrect for debugging.

Comment: show me more code please

Comment: Some code will help us understand this nice question more.

Comment: http://dev.flipkick.media for the full thing.

Comment: Please add included code in the question via an edit, please don't do so in a comment. It's quite hard to read that way.

Comment: Please take a look at your navigator console because you have an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: modal is not defined`.

Comment: I am playing round with this version as we speak. One sec Ill put it in a permanent location with code fixed...

Comment: Ok set a break point 277 flipkick.js, click the contact link, then click the (top right) close button on the modal that appears, then click contact again. I cant figure this one out!

Comment: Got ya stumped? :) I sometime wonder if jQuery actually saves me any time at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that jQuery caches data attributes.

Line 3614 - https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js

No idea why it is return the cached data for another object but I suspect Ive found a bug in the implementation as to how the cache retrieves data.

jQuery.removeData() will clear this cache.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not dynamically update its internal `data`. When using data-attributes, I target the attribute instead.

Check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/yrqpmqfy/):

```
// jQuery data - does not update dynamically
$(this).data('test');

// element attribute - does update dynamcially
$(this).attr('data-test')
```

Comment: I think the issue is that if you request a data attribute from a given element you expect to get the data back for the element and data attribute you specify. The cache in this case is returning the data attribute for a completely unrelated element. If you clear the cache you get the right results. If I set a similar code base up with less going on the return for the data function works correctly.